# sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Login

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm already trying the database function in first project. There is nothing wrong in first project. after that, im try with another project, but the result is *Sqlite Returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Login* .. im already checking the code from the previous project, everything is same but i have no idea why is it happend.

tool that i used is Eclipse Juno.

**MainActivity.java**
this is function that insert the data.

```
LoginEntity LoginE = new LoginEntity(LoginID, LoginPassword);
    LoginDA login = new LoginDA(this);
    login.open();
    login.createLogin(LoginE);
```

**LoginEntity.java**
this file is the class for Login (setter and getter)

```
public class LoginEntity {
private String LoginID;
private String LoginPassword;

public LoginEntity(){

}

public LoginEntity(String LoginID, String LoginPassword) {
    this.LoginID = LoginID;
    this.LoginPassword = LoginPassword;
}

public String getLoginID() {
    return LoginID;
}
public void setLoginID(String LoginID) {
    this.LoginID = LoginID;
}
public String getLoginPassword() {
    return LoginPassword ;
}
public void setLoginPassword(String LoginPassword) {
    this.LoginPassword = LoginPassword;
}
```

**LoginDA.java**
Database handler

```
public class LoginDA {
private static final String LoginID = "LoginID";
private static final String LoginPassword = "LoginPassword";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LecturerStudentAppointment";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Login";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                LoginID + " INTEGER PRIMARY, " +
                LoginPassword + " TEXT NOT NULL);"  );      
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
public LoginDA(Context c){
    ourContext =c;
}
public LoginDA open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);

    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close(){

}
public long createLogin(LoginEntity LoginEntity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(LoginID, LoginEntity.getLoginID());
    cv.put(LoginPassword, LoginEntity.getLoginPassword());
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure your table name is Login? Or LoginEntity?

Comment: yes.. _DATABASE_TABLE = "Login";_ LoginEntity as a class(constructor,setter and getter) ..or I have a mistake in declaring the database?

Answer (score 0):

A primary key is specified with `PRIMARY KEY`, not `PRIMARY`.

Also see [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run); you need to delete you app's old data.

Answer (score 0):

change the **db.execSQL** as:

=> remove the semicolon(;) from the SQL string.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                LoginID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                LoginPassword + " TEXT NOT NULL"+")");
```

it will be a better practice, if you write the SQL Query String in seperate and pass it inside execSQL();

Eg :

```
String SQL_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                LoginID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + LoginPassword + " TEXT NOT NULL"+")";

db.execSQL(SQL_QUERY);
```

Comment: The semicolon is optional and does not hurt. Why is using a separate variable a better practice?

Answer (score -1):

Is there any other table depending on 'Login'? If so, I think the error could be when you execute the DROP statement. Try to use CASCADE

Comment: no..there is no other table depending on it. ermmm..if it right what you are just saying, can you give to me the syntax for CASCADE..thank you :)

Comment: SQLite has no CASCADE, and does not check dependencies when dropping tables.

Comment: In the index 4.3 ON DELETE and ON UPDATE Actions of https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: That is not DROP TABLE.